# How to add realtime data from OPC client to user control using c#

Tags: c#

I created an OPC client to connect to KepServerEX, I got realtime data from KepServerEX and now I want to add realtime data to `user control` that contains a `textbox`.
Realtime data will be updated via `value_changed` event.

I created Windows Form Application and added `textbox` to Form to display realtime value, I can not post images here.

This is my code:

```
namespace OPC_Client
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    OPCServer KepServer;
    OPCGroups KepGroups;
    OPCGroup KepGroup;
    OPCItems KepItems;
    OPCItem KepItem;
    string strHostIP = "";
    string strHostName = "";
    bool opc_connected = false;
    int itmHandleClient = 0;
    int itmHandleServer = 0;


    private bool CreateGroup()
    {
        try
        {
            KepGroups = KepServer.OPCGroups;
            KepGroup = KepGroups.Add("OPCDOTNETGROUP");
            SetGroupProperty();
            KepGroup.DataChange += new DIOPCGroupEvent_DataChangeEventHandler(KepGroup_DataChange);
            KepGroup.AsyncWriteComplete += new DIOPCGroupEvent_AsyncWriteCompleteEventHandler(KepGroup_AsyncWriteComplete);
            KepItems = KepGroup.OPCItems;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void SetGroupProperty()
    {
        KepServer.OPCGroups.DefaultGroupIsActive = true;
        KepServer.OPCGroups.DefaultGroupDeadband = 0;
        KepGroup.UpdateRate = 1000;
        KepGroup.IsActive = true;
        KepGroup.IsSubscribed = true;
    }

    private void RecurBrowse(OPCBrowser OPCBrowser)
    {
        OPCBrowser.ShowBranches();
        OPCBrowser.ShowLeafs(true);

        listBox1.Items.Clear();
        foreach (object turn in OPCBrowser)
        {
            bool bl = turn.ToString().Contains("System") ;

            if (bl == false)
            {
                if (!Regex.IsMatch(turn.ToString(), @"^(\w+\.\w+\.\w+)$"))
                {

                }
                else
                {                        
                    listBox1.Items.Add(turn.ToString());
                }
            }

        }

    }


    private bool ConnectRemoteServer(string remoteServerIP, string remoteServerName)
    {
        try
        {
            KepServer.Connect(remoteServerName, remoteServerIP);                

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {        
            MessageBox.Show(""+ex);
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    // Write the TAG value when executed event
    void KepGroup_AsyncWriteComplete(int TransactionID, int NumItems, ref Array ClientHandles, ref Array Errors)
    {
        lblState.Text = "";
        for (int i = 1; i <= NumItems; i++)
        {
            lblState.Text += "Tran:" + TransactionID.ToString() + " CH:" + ClientHandles.GetValue(i).ToString() + "Error:" + Errors.GetValue(i).ToString();

        }

    }

    void KepGroup_DataChange(int TransactionID, int NumItems, ref Array ClientHandles, ref Array ItemValues, ref Array Qualities, ref Array TimeStamps)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= NumItems; i++)
        {
            if (Qualities.GetValue(i).ToString() == "192")
            {
              // add realtime value to texbox to display
                txtTagValue.Text = ItemValues.GetValue(i).ToString();
                txtQualities.Text = Qualities.GetValue(i).ToString();
                txtTimeStamps.Text = TimeStamps.GetValue(i).ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("disconnected to opc server");
                txtQualities.Text = Qualities.GetValue(i).ToString();
                txtTimeStamps.Text = TimeStamps.GetValue(i).ToString();
            }
        }
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (itmHandleClient != 0)
            {
                Array Errors;
                OPCItem bItem = KepItems.GetOPCItem(itmHandleServer);
                int[] temp = new int[2] { 0, bItem.ServerHandle };
                Array serverHandle = (Array)temp;
                KepItems.Remove(KepItems.Count, ref serverHandle, out Errors);
            }
            itmHandleClient = 1;
            KepItem = KepItems.AddItem(listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString(), itmHandleClient);
            itmHandleServer = KepItem.ServerHandle;
        }
        catch (Exception err)
        {
            itmHandleClient = 0;
            txtTagValue.Text = "Error ox";
            txtQualities.Text = "Error ox";
            txtTimeStamps.Text = "Error ox";
            MessageBox.Show("The reserved for system entry:" + err.Message, "message");
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //GetLocalServer();
        KepServer = new OPCServer();            
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!opc_connected)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (KepGroup != null)
        {
            KepGroup.DataChange -= new DIOPCGroupEvent_DataChangeEventHandler(KepGroup_DataChange);
        }

        if (KepServer != null)
        {
            KepServer.Disconnect();
            KepServer = null;
        }

        opc_connected = false;

    }

    private void btnSetGroupPro_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SetGroupProperty();

    }

    private void btnConnLocalServer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ConnectRemoteServer(txtRemoteServerIP.Text.Trim(), "KEPware.KEPServerEx.V5"))
            {
                return;
            }
            btnSetGroupPro.Enabled = true;
            opc_connected = true;

            GetServerInfo();

            RecurBrowse(KepServer.CreateBrowser());

            if (!CreateGroup())
            {
                return;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
        }
    }

    private void btnWrite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OPCItem bItem = KepItems.GetOPCItem(itmHandleServer);
        int[] temp = new int[2] { 0, bItem.ServerHandle };
        Array serverHandles = (Array)temp;
        Object[] valueTemp = new Object[] { "", txtWriteTagValue.Text };
        Array values = (Array)valueTemp;
        Array Errors;
        int cancelID;
        KepGroup.AsyncWrite(1, ref serverHandles, ref values, out Errors, 2009, out cancelID);
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
```

}

Now I want to create some User Controls to display some tag values.What should I do?

Comment: show us your code. What have you tried so far ?

Comment: I edited my article and showed my code. I created user control and displayed realtime value but couldn't update value via Value_Changed event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty big topic in itself, but I have implemented such a beast a few years back in C#, also using KepServerEx.

Without seeing your code it's a bit difficult for me to understand what you have done so far, but the general idea is that you want to handle the OPCGroup.DataChange event. From there you have to "dispatch" the changed value to the proper TextBox.

Of course, you have to setup your OPCServer, your OPCGroup(s) and so on.

I created a library for this, and it was some extensive work required, so I'm afraid it can't really be answered in one Q&A like here.

If you have a very specific question, please open another one and I'll try to answer more specifically.

Cheers

Comment: I created windows form application and added textbox to form to display tag value. I used OPCGroup.DataChange event to update value in textbox. Now I want to create some user controls to display tag value, but I don't know what to do.  OPCGroup.DataChange event can not use in user control.

Comment: I am trying to create library for my application, can you please help me?

Comment: @TuanNguyen Like I said, it's probably not possible to cover everything here. We would need to take this to some other platform. As a pointer, I have used an intermediate OpcTag class to do the binding between the DataChange event, and the Windows Forms Controls (DataBinding).

Comment: @TuanNguyen If you want, I have created a chat room here on StackOverflow. I'm located in the Eastern time zone, feel free to drop by and we can discuss OPC: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/83462/opcdotnet?tab=general

Comment: Luc Morin,Thank you so much for your enthusiastic helps. I'll join the chat room to discuss OPC with you.

Comment: Luc Morin, Unfortunately, I can't type message on chat room, I recieved notification from StackOverflow: " You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here ".

Comment: Well, try to answer a few questions ;-)

Comment: Luc Morin , Did you use Delegate and Event to do the binding between the DataChange event and the Controls?

Comment: Yes, I used custom event and delegates, I created an OPCTag class for example that "transports" the event between the OPCServerGroup and the Control. Like I said, it as a bit complex, took me a few weeks of coding :-)

Comment: It seems like everything is pretty hard for me to create an OPCTag class. 
I don't know where to start.

Comment: No. It was developed for a specific customer and I'm obviously not allowed to. Sorry.

Comment: Yes. I know. If I add many items to `OPCItem` using `OPCItem.AddItem()`, how to get data of each item if don't know `ClientHandle`?

Comment: I created a "tag" class that encapsulates the ClientHandle ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much, Luc Morin